# Notify on desktop using HTML5 Notifications API

Tags: feature-request, notifications

It would be nice to see opt-in notifications of activity on my desktop using the [HTML5 notifications api](http://www.paulund.co.uk/html5-notifications). Here is the [current browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=notifications) (all browsers except Internet Explorer).

[MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)

Comment: In the meantime, do check out [**StackApplet**](http://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-1-6-alpha-f) for something very similar!

Comment: Btw, StackApplet is currently broken. :-(

Comment: It's worth mentioning they already do this in chat.

Answer (score 26):

**Yes !** I believe this would be a very useful feature to have. I could get inbox notifications even when the browser is minimized, and I would not have to switch tabs to check if I have a new message all the time. Obviously, this feature should be opt-in.

It could look like this:

> [image: Screenshot]

I think this would be very useful !

Answer (score 7):

There is an extension for Chrome and Firefox on StackApps that basically does this: [Real-time desktop notifications for Stack Exchange inbox ( Chrome / Firefox )](https://stackapps.com/q/3780/28683)

I find it very useful.