# Feature Request: Enable (optional) opt-in sound on receiving a message or notification

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I don't know whether this topic is useful as in other user's context on SO, but in my opinion it is very much needed here.

Most of the time I came to SO and asks question, give answers, leave comments, etc. After doing so, either I have to keep the site open on the main window or I had to visit again and again (in case if site is not opened on main screen) to make sure that if there is a response on my answer, question or comment by any other user.

It would be better if there is a pop up sound each time whenever there is a notification or message (as in case of Facebook, pop up sound buzzes on receiving message), which let the user know about notification even if the SO on main window is not opened or user is browsing some other stuff in PC or any other tab in browser.

In my opinion, this will be the best which will make user to let him/her know even he/she is doing some multitasking.
Though this is not a social site but adding this feature will definitely make some difference.

What do you say?

Comment: Related :  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260346/notify-on-desktop-using-html5-notifications-api

Comment: You might want to check [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250762/how-can-i-make-stack-overflow-make-a-sound-when-a-new-question-appears/250769#250769) but I warn you, it did annoy the hell out of me during it's development and I'm not using that script.

Comment: As it is a feature-request I leave a downvote, and asdfasdfasdf

Comment: There are plenty of [apps for that](http://stackapps.com/?tab=apps); install one for your OS or browser. I use [Stackpop — Stack Exchange meets OS X Notification Center](http://stackapps.com/q/4523)

Comment: If you have a smartphone, the stackexchange app supports notifications by audio or vibration

Comment: Worth noting that chat already has audio notifications.

Comment: And another audio notification request, but for new answers instead of messages: [Is there a way to be notified with a sound when a new answer is received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299185/is-there-a-way-to-be-notified-with-a-sound-when-a-new-answer-is-received)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Audio notifications would be:

- Useless for anyone without speakers (not uncommon in office environments).
- Useless for deaf users.
- Annoying for me personally (Note: This is obviously the most important reason).

However, the general idea of being notified about new badges/messages/etc. is something that I wholeheartedly agree with, so I would suggest expanding your idea as follows:

- Allow (optional) audio notifications.
- Allow (optional) desktop "toast" notifications.
- Change the icon/title text of any Stack Overflow browser tabs to indicate that something has changed since you last looked at it.

Note the word "optional" here; users who hate these features would be able to turn them off, so hopefully everyone would be happy.

Disclaimer: I stole most (if not all) of these ideas from the [HipChat](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hipchat/info) web client. In my defence, they're good ideas, and worth stealing.

Comment: That will be the best... I think i must edit my question with **optional** word.

Comment: Make it opt-in, like email-notification, and it will be acceptable to me. Though I doubt it will be done anytime soon.