# Is there a way to be notified with a sound when a new answer is received?

Tags: support, answers

Is there a possibility to set a stackoverflow account to play some sound as a notification to new answer?

If there is not a built-in option, is there for example some chrome extension which can do that?

Comment: Look into using a UserScript and listening to Mutation events

Comment: If such a thing already exists, it's probably at [stack apps](http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script).

Comment: I don't know why you're getting down votes for something that isn't a feature request though.

Comment: @BSMP: Apparently people dislike the suggestion.

Comment: @BSMP I've retagged and edited the title maybe that prevents the initial knee-jerk reaction

Comment: @Cerbrus - That's the thing, it's not a suggestion. They're asking if it exists, not requesting that it be added.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in functionality to do that.

By leveraging the websockets you can achieve that as I demonstrated in my answer on [How can I make Stack Overflow make a sound when a new question appears?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250762/how-can-i-make-stack-overflow-make-a-sound-when-a-new-question-appears/250769#250769) over on Meta Stack Exchange.

It needs to be adapted for a different websocket event if you want it to play a sound on an answer but the mechanics remain the same. Explanation of the websockets can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218343/how-do-the-stack-exchange-websockets-work-what-are-all-the-options-you-can-send)