# Does Stack Overflow have in-browser notifications similar to Slack?

Tags: discussion, notifications

Does Stack Overflow have in-browser notifications similar to Slack?

I also was looking for some extension for Chrome as an option, but I could not find something useful. I would like to be notified if something new appears in my message box, or my scores change, or about new questions for my tags.

Comment: Duplicate of [Notify on desktop using HTML5 Notifications API](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260346/4642212).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not *quite*.  I've got a setup that does notify me of activity on Stack Overflow, but it's nothing official.

It's simply a combination of [Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/) and the official [Stack Exchange app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin).  I've got Pushbullet in my browser and on my phone, as well as the Stack Exchange app.  It's merely configured to listen to any event that hits the mobile app and it pushes it to my browser.

I doubt they'd ever come up with anything official, but it'd be *nice* I reckon...

Comment: Note that chat pings *do* have desktop notification capability, just nothing in your inbox.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET chat pings *do* end up in your inbox, after like 30 minutes or so. There's a setting in your chat profile where you can setup "quick notifications" to get them pretty much instantly.